# Changing file permissions works as root but not as sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have a really strange problem.  I have a few files in a large directory that I want to make readable by everyone.  So I try this:

`sudo find readme* -not -perm -o+r -exec chmod +r {} \;`

and get this:

`sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/find: Success`

I don't know why it says Success, because the permissions were not changed.  I verified by typing this:

`find readme* -not -perm -o+r -exec ls -l {} \;`

and get something like

```
-rw------- 1 root root 536871076 Nov 22 14:06 readme_20101122200429
-rw------- 1 root root 536871892 Nov 22 14:08 readme_20101122200642
-rw------- 1 root root 293458128 Nov 22 14:10 readme_20101122200859
```

as a last resort, I tried:

`sudo chmod +r *`

and got:

`sudo: unable to execute /bin/chmod: Success`

and again Success really means fail.  So, I gave up and logged in as root and tried:

`find readme* -not -perm -o+r -exec chmod +r {} \;`

This time it worked.  Why?

EDIT:  /etc/sudoers looks like:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

##Me
user1   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Comment: What does `/etc/sudoers` look like?

Comment: Could it be because the sudo does not roll over into the `-exec` part of the command, so the `find` was run as root, but the `chmod` was not?

Comment: @Ben Lee:  It's even stranger than that.  See my new line about `sudo chmod +r *`

Comment: Maybe your path is messed up. Type `echo $PATH` and see if it looks right. Also try `which find` and `which chmod`.

Comment: @Ben:  I thought that too.  The error ("Success") message shows that path of the executable.  I think it looks okay.

Comment: Wild guess, could you try `sudo 'sh -c "sudo chmod +r *"'`?  Sometimes sudo options prevent some commands from working.

Comment: It works for me. I thought you had busybox as a shell or something but those commands even work in busybox. Open a new terminal, if you haven't tried already:  I have had occasions where the shell had gotten corrupted, acted crazy, until I opened a new one.

Comment: I would think you have SELinux policy messed up. Try to switch SELinux into permissive mode to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know on wich version of find you are using. But, usually the first argument is the directory where to find, and if you want to filter on some filenames you have to use the -name argument. My guess will be

> sudo find . -name 'readme*' -not -perm -o+r -exec chmod +r {} \;

Do not forget to single-quote the file name pattern. If you don't, the * will be evaluated by the shell and not passed directly as an argument. This may explain the strange behaviour. Because in this case, probably the shell try to pass every filename matching readme* as arguments to sudo.

Comment: Commands he gave work perfectly fine for me with sudo so it probably isn't the case.

Comment: This flavor of command actually worked!  I have a LOT of files matching the pattern.  I think the * expands all of those files and overflows some buffer.  If I do a `-name` with the `readme*` pattern, it works fine.  I'm not sure why.  This was RHEL5.5 Sever.

Comment: @User1: It works fine to say find -name 'readme*' and not find readme* because in the latter case bash is expanding the glob into a list that overflows the command buffer and in the former case find is expanding the glob internally where no such restriction applies.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use:

```
sudo sh -c 'find readme* -not -perm -o+r -exec chmod +r {} \;'
```

This causes `sudo` to run the shell which then interprets the argument to `-c` as a shell script.   Using single-quotes around it is simplest - unless there are single quotes in the command to be executed.  In that case, each single quote in the command is replaced by four characters - `'\''`: quote, backslash, quote, quote.

However, in the context, I'd not want to guarantee that you wouldn't get:

```
sudo: unable to execute /bin/sh: Success
```

The odd error probably means that an `exec*()` family function call returned, but the value left in `errno` was zero.  That shouldn't happen - but apparently did.  What happens with:

```
sudo /bin/ls      # Or /usr/bin/ls if that's correct for your machine
```

When did you last check on the `sudo` installation?  When did you last reboot?  It looks like there is something screwball in the way `sudo` is (mis)handling the commands for you.

Is the directory you're working in NFS mounted?  Root typically has rather minimal privileges in such directories.  But the error should be of the EPERM (No permission) variety, not the 'success when failed' variety.